# Convert Current Timestamp to DD MMM YYYY format

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to convert current timestamp to DD MMM YYYY format.

but i don't know why it is giving me an error unparsable.

code:

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
Date fechaNueva = format.parse(ts.toString());

System.out.println(format.format(fechaNueva));
```

working but I want to do

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM YYY, HH:mm");
```

gives me error of unparsable.

**java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2014-10-07 15:38:29.876"**

Answer (score 1):

Following worked for me

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
Date fechaNueva = format.parse(ts.toString());
format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM YYY, HH:mm");
System.out.println(format.format(fechaNueva));
```

**Output:**

```
07 Oct 2014, 15:46
```

You were trying to parse date in a format you wanted it to be formatted instead of format in which it is already present.

Answer (score 1):

Simply u can do this

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
        System.out.println(timestamp);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM YYY, HH:mm");
        System.out.println("Formatted "+dateFormat.format(timestamp));
```

hope this helps.

OutPut:-

```
Formatted 07 Oct 2014, 15:59
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `ts.toString()`, you always need to use the same formatter.
Use just:

```
Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(new Date().getTime());
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM YYY, HH:mm");

System.out.println(format.format(ts));
```